# How to create custom legend in R using ggplot2 for horizontal lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a customized legend that labels the horizontal lines in my plot. I need the legend to state the following and also needs to be positioned out of the way of the blue lines that are plotted:

Acceptance Criteria:

Red line: "FoS = 1"

Orange line: "Anchor Uplift"

Steelblue line: "FoS = 2"

Green line: "FoS = 2.5"

[image: Plot without legend]

Here is my R code. Thanks so much!!

```
## Plot all Hs values
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("cyan", "blue"))
plotColors <- colfunc(length(unique(data$Wave.Height)))
# Initialize plot
plot1 <- ggplot(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_1ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force)) + 
  geom_line(color = plotColors[1], size = 1) + xlab("Wind Speed [knots]") + ylab("Total Force [MT]") + ggtitle("Current Speed 1 knot / Head Seas") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,75)) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_1ft$Total.Force), label = "1 ft", size = 6)
# Add all other lines
plot1 <- plot1 + geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_1.75ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[2], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_1.75ft$Total.Force), label = "1.75 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_2.5ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[3], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_2.5ft$Total.Force), label = "2.5 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_3.25ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[4], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_3.25ft$Total.Force), label = "3.25 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_4ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[5], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_4ft$Total.Force), label = "4 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_4.75ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[6], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_4.75ft$Total.Force), label = "4.75 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_5.5ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[7], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_5.5ft$Total.Force), label = "5.5 ft", size = 6) +
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_6.25ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[8], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_6.25ft$Total.Force), label = "6.25 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_7ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[9], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_7ft$Total.Force), label = "7 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_7.75ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[10], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_7.75ft$Total.Force), label = "7.75 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_8.5ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[11], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_8.5ft$Total.Force), label = "8.5 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_9.25ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[12], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_9.25ft$Total.Force), label = "9.25 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_line(data = hedron_1kt_180deg_10ft, aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force), color = plotColors[13], size = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 73.5, y = max(hedron_1kt_180deg_10ft$Total.Force), label = "10 ft", size = 6) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 506, color = "red", size = 1) + geom_hline(yintercept = 202, color = "lawngreen", size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 253, color = "steelblue", size = 1) + geom_hline(yintercept = 432, color = "orange", size = 1)
# Save plot
png(filename = "Hedron-WD=40ft-Heading=180deg-Uc=1knot.png", width = 800, height = 600)
plot1
dev.off()
```

Here is a link to sample data. You just need to change the working directory for the code to work

https://www.dropbox.com/s/htfm3h9s2rcajd4/Hedron%20and%20Arapaho%20Forces.csv?dl=0

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you provide a sample of the data used to create your plot. Paste the output of `dput(my.data.sample)` into your question.

Comment: I have added a link to the data used to create the plot above via a Dropbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plot like this with a lot less effort by putting your data frame in "long" format and then using aesthetic mappings to get the colors and legends.

You haven't provided sample data, so here's an example with fake data:

```
## Create some fake data

# Fake data
dat = do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(seq(1,10, length.out=8), function(i) {
  data.frame(level=i, x=1:100, y= 1:100 + 10*i)
}))

# Fake criteria lines
dat2 = data.frame(yint = c(40, 60, 149, 180), 
                  slope=c(-0.01,-0.05,-0.1, -0.08), Criteria=LETTERS[1:4])

library(dplyr)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=dat, aes(x,y, group=level), 
            colour=rep(hcl(210,100,seq(20,90,length.out=8)), each=100)) +
  geom_text(data=dat %>% group_by(level) %>% filter(x==max(x)),
            aes(label=round(level,2), x=x+1, y=y), hjust=0) +
  geom_abline(data=dat2, aes(intercept=yint, slope=slope, color=Criteria)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","orange","green","purple"))
```

Here's what's going on the code above:

1. `dat` contains the data we want to plot. `dat2` contains the data for the criteria lines for which we want to have a legend. Note that the data are in "long" format. For example, in `dat` the `level` column tells us to which grouping the `x` and `y` values belong.
2. `geom_line` plots the data. By setting `group=level` we get a separate line for each value of `level` with just one call to `geom_line`. Normally, we'd also add `color=level` inside `aes` to get a different color for each line. However, we want a legend for just the criteria lines, so we need to map colors to the data lines "by hand". That's what `colour=rep(hcl(210,100,seq(20,90,length.out=8)), each=100)` does (note that it's outside of `aes`).
3. `geom_text` places the value labels at the right end of each curve. Note that we filter the data so that we keep only right-most (x,y) value for each `level`, and we use that to place the text right next to each line.
4. `geom_abline` plots the `Criteria` lines. We use `color=Criteria` *inside* `aes` so that that the `Criteria` lines are plotted in different colors and we get a color legend.

Here's what the graph looks like:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Here's another example with the data you posted. I loaded your data file into a data frame called `df`. It looks like you subsetted your data, and I think the subset below is the same as the one in your question. Hopefully, you'll be able to generalize the examples below to whichever subset(s) you wish to include:

```
# Subset data
df.sub = df %>% filter(Barge.Name=="Hedron",
                       Heading==180,
                       Current.Speed==1,
                       Water.Depth==40)

ggplot(data = df.sub, 
       aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force, group=Wave.Height, color=Wave.Height)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_text(data=df.sub %>% filter(Wind.Speed==max(Wind.Speed)),
            aes(label=Wave.Height, y=Total.Force, x=Wind.Speed + 0.5), hjust=0) +
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]

You can also use faceting to include more variables in the visualization:

```
df.sub = df %>% filter(Current.Speed==1,
                       Water.Depth==40)

ggplot(data = df.sub, 
       aes(Wind.Speed, Total.Force, group=Wave.Height, color=Wave.Height)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_text(data=df.sub %>% filter(Wind.Speed==max(Wind.Speed)),
            aes(label=Wave.Height, y=Total.Force, x=Wind.Speed + 0.5), hjust=0) +
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(color=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(Barge.Name ~ Heading) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10,78))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that answered my question! I was able to plot a custom legend following your instructions. Looking at the sample data I provided for my code, how would I reduce the number of lines of code to one call to geom_line? When I try the method you suggest above I do not get the same graph. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. When I use the filter command, I get the following error message: "Error in match.arg(method) : object 'Water.Depth' not found". I have loaded plyr and am not sure what's causing this error.

Comment: I forgot to load install and load in dplyr package. Now everything is working perfectly. Thanks again!!!